# Sharing PHP singleton object between different users

Tags: php, singleton

I am working on a web application that lets users login and give an exam scheduled by the admin. I have an "accumulate" function that should run automatically once all the users have finished giving the test and update the database (according to some logic).

I know I can use the database to keep a store of users who are giving the test right now and accordingly run the logic but I am interested in knowing if this can be done by a singleton class.

My code:

```
class ScoreBoard{
  var $current;
  private static $board=NULL;
  // private static $current=0;
  private function __construct() {
    $this->current=0;
  }
  static function scoreboard(){
    if(!self::$board){
        self::$board= new ScoreBoard();
        $this->log("Created new");
        // return self::$board;
    }
    return self::$board;
  }
  function add(){
    $this->current+=1;
    $this->log("add ".$this->current);
  }
  function subtract(){
    $this->current-=1;
    $this->log("subtract ".$this->current);

    // file_put_contents("scoreboard.txt",self::$current);
    if($this->current<0)
        $this->current=0;
    if($this->current<=0)
        {
            $this->accumulate();
            self::$board=NULL;
        }
  }
}
```

And in the `startExam.php` file I am calling this function as :

```
$scoreboard= ScoreBoard::scoreboard();
$scoreboard->add();
```

And doing

```
$scoreboard= ScoreBoard::scoreboard();
$scoreboard->subtract();
```

when the exam ends. Thus, when each user starts the exam the singleton objects `add` function should be called and when he ends it the `subtract` function should be called. But this doesn't seem to work for some reason and the `$current` never increases beyond 1.

Kindly let me know if what I am trying to do is possible or not. And if there are any better ways to achieve what I want to do.Thank you.

Comment: No, php does not have shared memory. Each singleton is only unique to that particular request, 10 concurrent users will result in 10 'singleton' instances

Comment: Ohh Thank you for the help :) So using a database/file write is my only option? Also, to run the `accumulate` function, will I have to count all the entries in the database each time to check if this is the last user or is their any better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Memcached` to achieve this -

Your constructor function would then look something like this:

```
$this->memcache = new Memcached(); 
$this->memcache->addServer("127.0.0.1", "11211") // I think that's the right port for default.
$this->current = $this->memcache->get("current");
```

But you could do the same logic via storing the value in a file - and that would be easier...

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to avoid excessive file writes/database reads, but I suppose there isn't any way around it. Is Memcache faster than these options?

Comment: Memcache is the fastest -! I Highly recommend using it as your SESSION handler, as well.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used Memcache before but will give it a try now!